# Malfunctioning in ion-slides in Ionic2

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I implemented the `ion-slides` in building a gallery view. But one thing I noticed when I `ion-serve -l` the application was that **only iOS** followed the initial slides but Windows and Android always started from the first... Here is my code

**home.html**

```
<ion-content class="slide">
    <ion-slides [options]="slideOptions">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let element of list">
            <img src="{{element.image_path}}"/>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams, Slides} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
    slideOptions;
    list;

    constructor(private nav: NavController, private params: NavParams) {
            this.slideOptions = {
                initialSlide: 5,
                pager: true 
            };
        // Assume that the data is from the variable list I give values to here
    }
}
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using latest Ionic version below is the code will work with latest version.

You need to modify home.ts as below:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams, Slides} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

list;

constructor(private nav: NavController, private params: NavParams) {

}

ionViewDidEnter(){
  this.slides.slideTo(5);
}
}
```

and change home.html as below:

```
<ion-content >
<ion-slides pager>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let element of list">
        <img src="{{element.image_path}}"/>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

also you need to populate the list array.